# How to recurse a single list in prolog?

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am reading a tutorial and I find it hard to understand how to recurse a single list. Could someone give me a quick explanation of what the base case must be and why, and also what to do in the recursion. My code is:

```
type(string).

type(int).

instance(X,Y):- X, Y.

variable(_).

statement([]).

statement(A|B):- A, statement(B).
```

Purpose of the code is to make a light type checker to check things like this:

```
String s; int i; i = s.length();
```

I am passing this as a test:

```
statement([instance(type(string), variable(s))]).
```

I decided to put it in a list and recurse it and then just put it after the if. If it matches one of the rules, it'll be true. Currently I am just making sure I can get the type instantiation to work. Any help would be welcome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The base case should be with the list unifying with `[]`. As far as "doing it in the recursion" goes, do you really have a choice in Prolog?..

Comment: I mean, I am using swiprolog, pretty sure he wants us to use that. But how to I unify a list with []?

Comment: You write one rule that unifies with a head | tail `rule([H|T]) :- ...`, and another one that unifies with an empty list `rule([]) :- ...`.

Comment: I did that but its giving me an error. I'm going to post my code. Let me know how to correct it.

Comment: You are missing a pair of square brackets in `statement(A|B)`: it should be `statement([A|B])`. Also using `A` by itself in the rule does not make sense.

Comment: Why not? If the statement itself is unified, wouldn't that be true for the rule assuming one is found?

Comment: Could you put it as an answer. Unless you want to take it into a chat, which I would greatly appreciate! Either way, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Would it actually work if `A` unified with a valid rule? I'd be surprised, but then again I've been out of coding in Prolog since '95, so I'm definitely rusty. Did your program do what you expected after addition of square brackets?

Comment: Yes, I really appreciate it!. Add it as an answer to accept. By the way, is my recursion correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a pair of square brackets in

```
statement(A|B)
```

It should be

```
statement([A|B])
```

The rest of your recursive rule looks fine.

Comment: What exactly does statement([]). actually mean? How are they unified like that? Is it the equivalent of saying [] = []. ?